# ReaderWriterLockSlim and timer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, readerwriterlockslim

I have a frustration with ReaderWriterLockSlim and delaying ExitWriteLock.
Why is the WriteLock released in timers callback?

```
var _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
_lock.EnterWriteLock();
Assert.AreEqual(true, _lock.IsWriteLockHeld);   // good

System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer(state =>
{
    _lock.ExitWriteLock(); //throws exception that lock is not held
}, null, 1, -1);

Thread.Sleep(1000);
Assert.AreEqual(false, _lock.IsWriteLockHeld);
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you expect this code to do? What type is this `Timer`? Also, see MSDN: [`IsWriteLockHeld` returns _"a value that indicates whether **the current thread** has entered the lock in write mode"_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.iswritelockheld(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the looks of the constructor, you're using a `System.Threading.Timer`. The callback of that timer runs on a threadpool thread.

The write lock isn't released, it's just that the callback you specified for the Timer runs on a different thread, and that thread *doesn't* hold the write lock, so the assertion `Assert.AreEqual(true, _lock.IsWriteLockHeld);` in the callback fails, causing an exception.

One thread enters a lock, and only for that thread does `IsWriteLockHeld` hold true, and only that thread can exit the lock.

Comment: I've edited the question, ExitWriteLock also throws exception. But let me guess, only a thread, that holds a lock can exit it ?

Comment: @aershov you can use a SemaphoreSlim here if you don't need reader-writer semantics.